# release compile VS2013

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

we have a problem with release compile of a function

```
int db_add_file(int aDbHandle, int aVisibility, int aSkipFlag)
{ // vs holds aVisibility in register r14
   fmExecuteimportScript(aDbHandle); // call function in a dll
   // after these call the register r14 is different
   DbFile.Add(aVisibility, aSkipFlag); // these call will fail because of the r14 
}
```

Happens only in release build! is these a bug of vs or the dll?

Comment: According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9z1stfyw.aspx) r14 is one of the registers that must be preserved by the callee, so it looks like the dll is to blame.

Comment: Yes it looks you are right

Comment: Also you should add `return` statement.